# nmap scan service and port for ssl ciphers

Tags: ssl, nmap

When i run the command

nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers hostname

I get the output of ciphers with a grade next to it. For example :

|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - D
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - A

My question is What is A - D stand for ? I assume A being the highest and best. Is it right ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A-D stand for strength.
Using nmap (https://nmap.org) to scan SSL cipher you can see report like below:

> nmap -p 443 --script ssl-enum-ciphers example.com
>
> TLSv1.2:
>      ciphers:
>        **TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 768) - C
>        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (dh 768) - C
>        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 768) - B
>        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (dh 768) - B
>        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp160k1) - A
>
>        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp160k1) - A
>
>        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp160k1) - A
>
>        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp160k1) - A
>
>        TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
>
>        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
>
>        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
>
>        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
>
>        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A**
>      compressors: 
>        NULL
>      cipher preference: client
>      warnings:
>        64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
>         Key exchange (dh 768) of lower strength than certificate key
>         Key exchange (secp160k1) of lower strength than certificate key
>     **least strength: C**

See the bold text. First bold lines are ciphers with corresponding strength. And last bold line is summary strength based on minimum ciphers strength.